# Firebase An internal error has occurred. [ Bad Request ]

Tags: android, firebase

I did firebase signineithemailandpassword, it was working fine till today morning, but now it's giving me:

```
An internal error has occurred. [ Bad Request ]
```

My signineithemaiandpassword code is following:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    //
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {

                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterationActivity.this, "User already registered!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return;
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterationActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Log.e("Fail",task.getException().getLocalizedMessage());
                                        return;
                                    }

                                } else {

                                    Registration reg = new Registration();
                                    reg.setName(name1);
                                    reg.setmobilenum(phone);
                                    reg.setcpwd(confirmp);
                                    reg.setpwd(pwd);
                                    database.child("Registration").child(name1).setValue(reg);
                                    User myUser = User.getInstance(realm);
                                    realm.beginTransaction();
                                    myUser.setLogin(true);
                                    realm.commitTransaction();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    verifyPhoneNumber(phone, mCallbacks);
                                }
                            }

                        });
```

So , now please tell me what's issue in signin auth, today my client is going to test it so please help me hurry.

Thanks

Comment: Any solution yet ?